# Could not determine the parameter type of a parameter not even used in the query

Tags: sql, node.js, express

I came across this issue while parameterizing my queries on ExpressJS:

```js
pool.query(
  {
    text: `UPDATE person
    SET ${[
      title ? `title = $2` : ``,
      birth ? `birth = $3` : ``,
      death ? `death = $4` : ``,
      summary ? `summary = $5` : ``,
    ]
      .filter((property) => property !== ``)
      .join(`,`)} WHERE id = $1`,
    values: [id, title, birth, death, summary],
  },
  (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows);
  },
);
```

id, title, birth, death and summary are provided by my update request, but some of them may not be present. For example, I was testing with just birth and death in my request body. This returned an error of "could not determine data type of parameter $2." This is really weird to me since the query sent to postgresql doesn't even contain the placeholder $2. Is there any way around this for me to only update columns provided by the request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter means there could be fewer than 5 parameters but you're still passing an array of 5 values to bind. See the problem?

According to the MySQL docs, you *should* be able to do something like this instead (though I haven't tested it)

```js
// create an object with non-empty values
const set = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries({ title, birth, death, summary }).filter(
    ([, val]) => val !== "",
  ),
);

pool.query(
  {
    text: `UPDATE person SET ? WHERE id = ?`,
    values: [set, id],
  },
  (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows);
  },
);
```

---

Otherwise, you can create the `text` and `values` array from the same set of data

```js
// create a filtered array of key / value pairs
const set = Object.entries({ title, birth, death, summary }).filter(
  ([, val]) => val !== "",
);

pool.query(
  {
    text: `UPDATE person SET ${set
      .map(([key]) => `${key} = ?`)
      .join(", ")} WHERE id = ?`,
    values: [...set.map(([, value]) => value), id],
  },
  (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows);
  },
);
```

Comment: The second solution is quite neat, thanks a lot! Seems like I've got a long way to go with APIs

Comment: @minhok1 out of interest, did the first solution work? I wasn't sure if you could have an array of values where one was an object

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - but not because of the logic itself, but more so from the question mark syntax. Even for the second solution, I used the map index to assign placeholders of $number format instead of question marks.